# How to get straight exception stack trace at JAX-RS client side

Tags: java, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I am using REST services in my project, and I created a filter to log the error when there is an unsuccessful service invocation, but how to use the resteasy client to capture the error stack trace.

```
public class MyLogResponseFilter implements ClientResponseFilter {
    ...
    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext,
            ClientResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        if (responseContext.getStatus() != Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
            if (responseContext.hasEntity()) {
                String body = IOUtils.toString(responseContext.getEntityStream(), "UTF-8");
                log.error("Error with status={}, statusInfo={}, message={}", 
                        responseContext.getStatus(),
                        responseContext.getStatusInfo(),
                        body);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code works, but the resteasy wrapped the error stack into html body, e.g. what's read out from responseContext.getEntityStream() is like that:

```
Error with status=500, statusInfo=Internal Server Error, message=<html><head><title>ERROR</title><style>body {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 5px;
}

.header {
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(153,151,153) 8%, rgb(199,199,199) 54%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(153,151,153) 8%, rgb(199,199,199) 54%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(153,151,153) 8%, rgb(199,199,199) 54%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(153,151,153) 8%, rgb(199,199,199) 54%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(153,151,153) 8%, rgb(199,199,199) 54%);

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0.08, rgb(153,151,153)),
        color-stop(0.54, rgb(199,199,199))
    );
    color: black;
    padding: 2px;
    font-weight: normal;
    border: solid 1px;
    font-size: 170%;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    height: 32px; 
}
.error-div {
   display: inline-block;   width: 32px;   height: 32px;    background: url('data:image/png;base64,longEncryptedPath') left center no-repeat;
}.error-text-div {
   display: inline-block;   vertical-align: top;   height: 32px;}.label {   font-weight:bold;   display: inline-block;}.value {   display: inline-block;}</style></head><body><div class="header"><div class="error-div"></div><div class="error-text-div">Error processing request</div></div><div class="label">Context Path:</div><div class="value">/my-webservice</div><br/><div class="label">Servlet Path:</div><div class="value">/services</div><br/><div class="label">Path Info:</div><div class="value">/mypath</div><br/><div class="label">Query String:</div><div class="value">usridNbr=1000001</div><br/><b>Stack Trace</b><br/>org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.RuntimeException: ====test it<br/>org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76)...Long stack trace</body></html>
```

I only need to catch the error message and error stack trace, any advice to easily achieve that without parsing the html body. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register an [ExceptionMapper](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-rev-a/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) which maps your Exception to an entity that can be easily parsed. Here's a quick+dirty example mapping a RuntimeException to JSON:

```java
@Provider
public class RuntimeExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<RuntimeException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(RuntimeException exception) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("exception", exception.getClass().getName());
        map.put("message", exception.getMessage());
        return Response.status(500).entity(map).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).build();
    }

}
```

On the client side you could filter it like this:

```java
@Override
public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext, ClientResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
    if (responseContext.getStatus() == 500 && responseContext.hasEntity()) {
        Map error = new ObjectMapper().readValue(responseContext.getEntityStream(), Map.class);
        LOG.error("Status: {}, Exception: {}, Message: {}", 
            responseContext.getStatus(), error.get("exception"), error.get("message"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @lefloh. I thought it might be something to do with the server side, but I couldn't find a proper example about how to build a response with error detail populated, and your sample really address that.